# LEFT JOIN usando Linq

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
Responsavel             |     Filho
Id      Nome            |     Id    Nome           ResponsavelId
1       Ana             |     1     Aninha         1
2       Maria           |     2     Ana Júlia      1
3       Pedro           |     3     Mariazinha     2
```

Gostaria de fazer um `SELECT` com `INNER JOIN` onde apresentasse o seguinte resultado:

```
Id    Responsavel     Filho
1     Ana             Aninha
1     Ana             Ana Júlia
2     Maria           Mariazinha
3     Pedro           NULL
```

Para isso estou usando `Left Join` no **SQL Server**.

```
SELECT 
    Responsavel.Id
    Responsavel.Nome,
    Filho.Nome
FROM Responsavel
LEFT JOIN Filho
    ON Responsavel.Id = Filho.ResponsavelId
```

Como posso fazer isso usando **Linq**?

Comment: Tem que ser Linq exatamente? Ou pode ser *extension methods* do EF?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356439/left-join-in-linq-to-entities Acho que aqui pode te ajudar.

Comment: Sim @CiganoMorrisonMendez , mas o que seria esse _extension methods_ do EF? Estou usando o Entity Framework mesmo!

Comment: @Marconi não manjo muito bem de inglês amigo... E o translate lasca tudo.

Comment: Linq parece um SQL. *Extension Methods* é aquele modo do EF mais ou menos assim: `db.Entidade.Where(...).Select(...)`. Entendeu?

Comment: Sim, ótimo! Pode ser em _Extension Methods_ mesmo. Por favor, considere `db.Responsavel` e `db.Filho`. Ficarei muito grato se puder me ajudar @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues ok, acho que o Cigano vai te ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considerando *Extension Methods* sobre Entity Framework, não existe exatamente o conceito de `LEFT JOIN`. O que existe é uma carga de `Responsavel` que pode ou não ter `Filho`.

Ou seja, imagino que seu `Responsavel` esteja modelado da seguinte forma:

```cs
public class Responsavel 
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Filho> Filhos { get; set; }
}

public class Filho
{
    ...
    public virtual Responsavel Responsavel { get; set; }
}
```

Neste caso, a seleção ficaria da seguinte forma:

```cs
var responsaveisEFilhos = db.Responsavel
                          .Include(r => r.Filhos)
                          .ToList();
```

Apenas isso seleciona todos os `Responsaveis` e seus `Filhos`. Se quiser apenas os três campos, fica assim:

```cs
var responsaveisEFilhos = db.Responsavel
                          .Include(r => r.Filhos)
                          .ToList();
var listaComoJoin = responsaveisEFilhos 
                          .SelectMany(r => r.Filhos)
                          .Select(f => new 
                          {
                              ResponsavelId = f.ResponsavelId,
                              ResponsavelNome = f.Responsavel.Nome,
                              FilhoNome = f.Nome
                          })
                          .ToList();
```

Mas repare que isso fica meio fora de propósito. Você já havia selecionado `Filho` no primeiro comando, mas sem desnormalizar os dados. Usando os *Extension Methods*, a forma de pensar na seleção não é mais como um `join` do SQL, e sim como uma entidade e seus dados dependentes.

Agora, se você **realmente** quer usar o Linq, então fica da seguinte forma:

```cs
var responsaveisEFilhos = (
    from responsaveis in db.Responsaveis
    from filhos in db.Filhos
        .Where(f => f.ResponsavelId == responsaveis.Id)
    select new {
        ResponsavelId = responsaveis.Id,
        ResponsavelNome = responsaveis.Nome,
        FilhoNome = filhos.Nome
    }
).ToList();
```

Mas isso não tem otimização alguma, e você não trabalha com todas as informações das entidades, algo que vejo como uma desvantagem.